# Passing variables to functions, and using multiple files with classes

Tags: c++

I have a variable called SDL_Renderer* gRenderer. This variable is stated in private, in a header file called initialization. There is a function also declared public within the header file.

bool Initial();

the Initial function changes the value of gRenderer from NULL, to something different.

I want to access the different variable from a different class, in a different function. Whenever I use friend classes, it returns me the value NULL.

This is the main function that runs each function within the class

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Initialize mainkey;
    mainkey.Initial();

    Overworld key;

}
```

Partt of the function Initial that changes the gRenderer value.

```
gRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer( gWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED );
        if( gRenderer == NULL )
        {
            printf("Renderer Failed to be created! Check Initialize Function!! SDL Error: %s\n",         SDL_GetError() );
            InitialStart = false;
        }
```

and the part of a function in a different class that wants to use the changed value in Initial.

```
Initialize bgkey;
        //Create texture from surface pixels
        newBG = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface( bgkey.gRenderer, LoadedImage );
            if( newBG == NULL )
            {
                printf("Unable to create texture properly! SDL Error", path.c_str(), IMG_GetError() );
            }
```

Comment: Do you *declare* or do you *define* `gRenderer` in the header? And what do you mean with it being private??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never declare global variables in the header files. When you use some header with the `#include` directive, it entire content is simply inserted in the source c/cpp file. If you include header with the global variable in two source files it means, that **two** copies of this global variable are created. So in your `mainkey.Initial` you change one variable, but in the `Overworld` class you trying to access completely different one. To prevent such situation you should declare your global variable in some source cpp file and create link to it in the corresponding header using keyword `extern`.

```
extern SDL_Renderer* gRenderer;
```